# How to fix "java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create job" in a Dataflow template job that writes to BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to use the JDBC to BigQuery Dataflow [template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#java-database-connectivity-jdbc-to-bigquery) to copy data from a Postgres database to BigQuery. But my Dataflow job is failing and I'm running into this error below:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create job with prefix beam_bq_job_LOAD_jdbctobigquerydataflow0releaser1025092115d7a229e9_214eff91b59f4b8d863809d3865504fa_11cbacad09f05e44363d2dd2963e9fd1_00001_00000, reached max retries: 3, last failed job: null.

at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryHelpers$PendingJob.runJob ( org/apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery/BigQueryHelpers.java:200 )
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryHelpers$PendingJobManager.waitForDone ( org/apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery/BigQueryHelpers.java:153 )
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables$WriteTablesDoFn.finishBundle ( org/apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery/WriteTables.java:378 )
```

I saw other stack overflow posts and have already tried the following:

1. Ensure that Dataflow worker service account is granted BigQuery Admin and BigQuery User role for the dataset I'm writing to.
2. Database is not too large - I'm only copying <10 rows since I'm just testing it out.
3. Ensure that schema in Postgres DB is the same with BigQuery table's schema.

The solutions above still didn't work, anything else I can try? Thanks!

Comment: Is there any additional stacktrace/cause? Can you check the job on BigQuery to see if there's any meaningful error/exception there?

Comment: There is no additional information from the stacktrace other than the above. And I also inspected "Project History" of BigQuery and there seems to be no job running in there so there were no errors from BigQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the project where the dataset is located different to the one where Dataflow is running? If they are different, you will need to assign the BigQuery User role in the Dataflow project. The BigQuery job is initiated in that project.

(the BigQuery Admin role for the destination dataset would remain as is)

Comment: My dataflow job and BigQuery dataset reside in the same GCP project. Any other possible cause?

Comment: The BigQuery user is a project level role. Are you assigning it to the dataset only? Or  at the project level?

Comment: I did assign the BigQuery user role to the dataset instead of at the project level. That fixed the error. Thanks so much!